# Whenever I am taking notes, I write down what the teacher taught / has taught - are both acceptable?

Tags: meaning, tense, present-perfect

When it is a statement about a habit, a regular event, or things like that, what tense do we use in a noun clause: simple past or present perfect?

**Example 1**

> Whenever I am taking notes, I write down what the teacher taught.

**Example 2**

> Whenever I am taking notes, I write down what the teacher has taught.

In my view:
I guess both are acceptable, but British English speakers might think it is better to use present perfect because they tend to perceive simple past is a single past event.
However, I am not sure. Can anyone shed light on this topic?

Comment: Do you mean that you often take notes and those times you write down what the teacher taught?

Comment: Is teaching, is best here.

Answer (score 1):

You use present simple to describe current habitual activities:

> Whenever I take notes, I write down what the teacher teaches.

You would only use a past tense to describe a past (and no longer current) habitual action:

> Whenever I took notes, I wrote down what the teacher taught.

You would only use present perfect if the writing occurs after the teaching:

> At the end of each day, I write down everything that the teacher has taught that day.

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, but the present perfect is defter, as typically notes are written down soon after a teacher has uttered something noteworthy, not long after. You are describing your practice of taking notes while the utterance is still "fresh".